# sort from the central of file

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

I have a file full of random string, like below, I would like to sort the file from the middle to start and end. 
If the total lines are odd, I would like to start from the central line, then central-1, central+1, central-2, central+2.
If the total lines are even, I would like to start from the floor of the total lines/2, vice versa.

The file is about 100MB, I'm running on a VPS with 2G ram.

I can use tools under unix-like platform. How do I do that? 
Please let me know if there's a name for such number sequence.
Thanks.

```
-----------------BEFORE
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
-----------------

-----------------AFTER
line4
line3
line5
line2
line6
line1
line7
-----------------
```

Comment: How is that `sorted from the middle`? What does that phrase mean?

Comment: @EdMorton: I agree it isn't clear, but I think that the first line in the sorted output is the central line, line4, then the preceding and following lines (3, 5), then ones either side of that (2, 6), and finally (1, 7).  It's an unusual sort!  Presumably, if there were an even number of lines such as 8 lines, you'd start with (4, 5), then (3, 6), then (2, 7), and (1, 8).

Comment: @Tienfu: is the input always in ascending sequence 1, 2, 3, …?  Are the values contiguous (no gaps between the numbers)?  Can you use the number embedded in the lines, or do you have to go by the initial position of the line?  How big is the file?  Can you store all the lines in memory?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah looks like you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are an even number of lines, N, in the input, you start with line N÷2, then add +1, -2, +3, -4, … to get the next entries in the sequence.  If N = 8, the sequence is 4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1, 8.

If there are an odd number of lines, N, in the input, you start with line (N+1)÷2, then add -1, +2, -3, +4, … to get the next entries in the sequence.  If N = 7, the sequence is 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7.

This can be implemented fairly simply in `awk` by slurping the lines of input into an array, and then printing them in the sequence demonstrated.

---

```
$ cat script.awk
{ line[++N] = $0 }
END {
    if (N > 0)
    {
        j = (-1) ** (N % 2)
        n = int((N + 1) / 2)
        for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            print line[n]
            n += j * i
            j = -j
        }
    }
}
$ seq -f "line%.0f" 1 7 | awk -f script.awk
line4
line3
line5
line2
line6
line1
line7
$ seq -f "line%.0f" 1 8 | awk -f script.awk
line4
line5
line3
line6
line2
line7
line1
line8
$
```

Comment: Thanks, I will start to write the awk script, just wondering if there's a name for the such number sequence.

Comment: I've not heard of a name for such a sequence, but there probably is one.